# np.where() with multiple outputs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am currently performing a row-wise calculation on a `pd.DataFrame` using `df.apply(foo)`, where `foo` is effectively as follows:

```
def foo(row):
    n = row['A']
    d = row['B']

    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if d <= 0:
        return 100
    return n / d * 100
```

This seems to be begging to be simplified into an `np.where`.

I have other cases with only one `if` statement (i.e. `if n <= 0`), which I have already simplified into

```
np.where(df['A'] <= 0, 0, df['A'] / df['B'])
```

However, I can't see how to do the same with the double-if case. At least not elegantly. I could do

```
np.where(df['A'] <= 0, 0, np.where(df['B'] <= 0, 100, n / d * 100))
```

But this would seem to run through the entire dataframe twice, once for each `np.where` call.

Is there a better way of doing things? Or, alternatively, is the use of `np.where` and the vectorization it brings so great that running through the table twice with `np.where` is still better than only once with `pd.apply`?

Comment: `np.select((condA, condB), (seriesA,seriesB), default=seriesC)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, now I feel silly. completely forgot about  `np.select`. Feel free to write a quick answer for a free green tick.

Comment: haha, it happens. Cheers.

Comment: @Erfan, yeah, not a duplicate of the question, but this is certainly answered in the accepted answer.

Comment: Just because your question is already answered, it's best to close it, thats why I flagged it